# An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.WebPages.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

Trying out MVC for the first time and when I used "enable migrations" in my Merchant class to update my database and ran it I got the above error.  Saw a few others on Stack with similar errors but those seemed easy to fix.

This is:   _ViewStart.cshtml

```
    @{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
```

THe problem is that there is no such Layout.cshtml in my project, so obviously it won't find it.  So is it ok to delete the ViewStart page?

I am not sure if you need more information so if you do let me know and I will add it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somehow my original Layout file was erased or moved somewhere to where I couldn't find it.  SO answered it myself.